# How to install XCGLogger?

Tags: swift, xcglogger

I want to add the XCGLogger Framework to my project.

At the [XCGLogger github page](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger) is a "how to use"-section and a also a demo project. Some tasks are not quite clear for me. Therefore some questions:

1. "Add the XCGLogger project as a subproject to your project" - Does it mean to simply drag the "Library"-Folder into to my project folder in the project navigator?
2. "and add either the iOS library as a dependancy of your target(s)" - How am I doing that?
3. What do I have to do at the Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme ... Menu? Because I don't want the framework in my release build.

Comment: Did you try asking them directly? (and tell them to set their library up as a pod)

Comment: @nhgrif They do use pods actually. There is a podspec in their repository. It's not their fault that some developers don't know how to set up project dependencies...

Comment: @Sulthan Then how come their "How to Use" section doesn't start with how to install it as a pod?

Comment: @nhgrif Why should it, really? If you have ever installed one pod, you can install them all. But the real reason is that the owner doesn't use pods and pod support came from a PR and the author didn't think of updating readme.

Comment: @Sulthan Because a "How to Install" section that says "Just add this single line to your podfile:" is the best advertisement for using podfiles (and getting more new people using them) that there is.